# Spring 3 bean instantiation sequence

Tags: java, spring

Is there anyway to specify order in which beans to be instantiated? i.e. I want specific beans to be instantiated before other beans, its like startup sequence.

I am using Spring 3.2 and annotation based declaration method.

Comment: In my practice instantiation sequence is equal to order in xml config file. But there may be exceptions..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If bean *A* depends on bean *B* by defining `<property/>`, `@Autowired` or `<constructor-arg/>` then the order is forced and fixed by the Spring container. No problem here.

But if you want to enforce specific order of bean creation which is not expressed via explicit dependencies feel free to use:

```
<bean id="A" depends-on="B"/>
<bean id="B"/>
```

or better (with annotations, works also with `@Bean` Java configuration):

```
@Service
@DependsOn("B")
public class A {}
```

or even better... don't use it. These constructs are a code smell and often suggest you have some nasty invisible dependency between your components.

Answer (score 7):

Agreed with the answer provided by Tomasz. If you know that bean A depends on bean B then this is right approach.

Sometimes you have logic that should be executed before all beans instantiation. In this case you can use [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html). Spring creates and executes BeanFactoryPostProcessors first and after that only all other beans. At the same time if your BeanFactoryPostProcessor depends on some bean A you can use property or constructor injection. In this case Spring will create bean A first, then your BeanFactoryPostProcessor, call BeanFactoryPostProcessor and after that only instatiate all other beans in the context.

Comment: I used this to set the spring.active.profile setting from a system properties file. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ordered interface on your bean to define ordering relative to other beans.

Answer (score 0):

Further，if you use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as emamedov said, `Ordered` interface can be implemented to control `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instance sequence.