# Does Spring replaces method calls with existing bean in java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Am I right that method `loadView` will be called only once (when creating `mainView` bean)?

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "mainView")
    public View getMainView() throws IOException {
        return loadView("fxml/main.fxml");
    }

    @Bean
    public MainController getMainController() throws IOException {
        return (MainController) getMainView().getController();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step1Controller getStep1Controller() throws IOException {
        return getMainController().getStep1Controller();
    }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All spring beans are singleton by default. So if you are not in a `@Configuration` simply your answer is **YES**.

**CAUTION:** In your situation if you call `getMainView` more than once while creating other beans which happens in `@Configuration`, it will be called multiple times, but just while creating.

Furthermore, I recommend you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence).

Comment: Well actually no.... `@Configuration` are special beans and are processed specially. So while the method is *apparently* called multiple times the same instance of the bean is returned. The configuration class is actually proxied/extended by cglib and is parsed at by using asm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, nevertheless I've pointed this out in my answer. @M.Deinum I've added a CAUTION keyword in it to make it more readable