# How to create a database during spring context initialization

Tags: mysql, spring, datasource, javabeans

I need to create a database named test in my local mysql server which i will use to setup my datasource bean. I am using the following spring configuration for setting up the datasource and jdbctemplate for my testing

```
@Configuration
class Config {
        @Bean(initMethod = "setupDatabase")
      public DataSource getDataSource() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(
                url, settings.getUsername(), settings.getPassword());
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource;
      }

      @Bean
      public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(((DataSourceTransactionManager)transactionManager()).getDataSource());
        return jdbcTemplate;
      }

      @Bean
      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource());
      }

      @Bean
      public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
      }

      private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        return populator;
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void setupDatabase() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        try {
          Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, settings.getUsername(), settings.getPassword());
          Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
          statement.execute("create database test");
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
          LOGGER.error("Could not setup database for test", exception);
          throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error Caused by:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46)
```

Can someone explain what is going wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the test database at your local mysql? You need to create the db first to connect from your application. If you want to create a database by executing sql query connect to the database as root user and create the db.

Comment: I want to be able to create the database programatically when the spring context is initialized. If I create the database manually, it works; but I want to be able to create that database during context initialization and use it in my beans

Answer (score 0):

The source of the exception: your `setupDatabase()` method is executed actually by Spring **AFTER** `getDataSource()` cause `@Bean(initMethod = "setupDatabase")` forces Spring to execute `initMetod` **AFTER** a bean creation for the bean  *initialization*. But it's not you expect here.

You need somehow define your `getDataSource()` *is depended* on `setupDatabase()`. E.g. with a help of [@DependsOn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation.

Also see [Spring 3 bean instantiation sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence)

**P.S.** but why you don't simple manually add `setupDatabase()` call into `getDataSource()` method?