# How to control sequence of Spring beans creation?

Tags: java, spring

I am using some third-part jars that PARTLY migrated to spring. The pain point is that there are lots of initialization module that mot migrated to spring. There initialization module need to be executed first before lots' of beans creation.

I also read [Spring 3 bean instantiation sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence), the problem here is, the third part library uses @Component for bean creation (which depends on initialization module that not migrated to spring, wired right...?).

Now I can write a spring bean to wrap all initialization modules. And create the bean before beans that need it.

So is there a way to specify the bean creation sequence to create the  initialization bean first?

Also I checked some documents, spring bean creation is in single thread so this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put the wraperBean that initialize as the first Bean in your xmlConfig file then spring will process the initialization by initializing that Wraper  An other solution is to add `depends-on` attribute to all your beans that depend on that Wrapper and you specify the id of that wrapper bean inside the attribute `depends-on` like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="modules" class="com.mycompany.ModulesWrapper" />
<bean class="com.foo.ClientBean" depends-on="modules" />
</beans>
```

Comment: The complex part is there are too many beans and need to enable scan to create these beans. Seems the order in spring xml doesn't work for scan?

Comment: did you try to put <context:component-scan base-package="package.beans.instatiated.last"/> at the end of the xml configuratoin file this will force spring to instanciate these beans at the end

Comment: if this doesn't work can you post you configuration File

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeanPostProcessor and add your initizaling module as the dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<bean class="com.foo.CustomBeanPostProcessor" depends-on="com.foo.InitModuleBean"/>
<bean class="com.foo.BarBean" />
<bean id="com.foo.InitModuleBean" class="com.foo.InitModuleBean" />
</beans>
```