# Missing an event in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring application events to send information to other beans. There's a bean A that publishes an event as soon as A is initialised. And there is a bean B that listens for the events sent by A.

Depending on the time A is initialised among the other beans, B gets initialised to late, and misses the event sent by A.

How is it intended in Spring to circumvent such issues? Is there any other way than changing the bean initialisation order?

Comment: Check this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence

Answer (score 1):

One probable way is to use

> depends-on

attribute.You may define the dependency in case you are using

Xml configuration:

```
<bean id="A" depends-on="B"/>
```

Annotation based:

```
@DependsOn("B")
public class A {}
```

This forces spring to intialize B before A so that it will not miss the event published by A.

Comment: Instead of XML you can (and should) use the corresponding [annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html).

Comment: I believe you have mentioned the link of annotation based instead of xml.. its not opening although plz verify. OP has not mentioned if he is on XML or Annotation based.

Comment: Yes, I linked the corresponding annotation for the sake of completeness, so OP can chose either.

Comment: This method works, but the consequence is that the author of A needs to know the names of all consumers, which is exactly the thing you want to bypass when using the observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `init()` method in your beans, and then in your `main` function make calls to `init()` methods of each bean. You can order the calls as you like there, and particularly call to A's `init()` before B's one.
Then you'll have to put the publishing of event of bean A into A's `init()` method.