# Spring bean instantiation order

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I'm new to spring, have a basic question.

I have 3 classes say for example Class A, B and C. I want to instantiate them in sequential order.
Class B can only instantiate only after Class C instantiation. Class A can instantiate only after Class B.

how to configure this?

Sounds may silly, forgive :)

Comment: Hi, please see post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence

Comment: Thanks @Rentius2407

Answer (score 3):

use dependson

```
<bean id="beanA" class="com.package.A"  depends-on="beanB"/>
<bean id="beanB" class="com.package.B" depends-on="beanC"/>
<bean id="beanC" class="com.package.C" />
```

Comment: Thanks :) @kuhajeyan

Answer (score 0):

Also beans don't need to depend on each other to force custom ordering. For independent beans you can use @Order annotation

```
@Component
@Order(2)
public class A implements SomeInterface{}

@Component
@Order(3)
public class B implements SomeInterface{}
```