# Spring @DependsOn inheritance behavior

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have an abstract class `A` and a bunch of subclasses, which are Spring beans defined using `@Service` annotation (`A` itself is not annotated). And I also have some separate bean of type `B`.

What I need to achieve is to make all these `A`-beans to be initialized **after** bean `B`.

For now I've used `@DependsOn('b')` with all of these beans - and it worked. But I don't want to copy-paste this annotation for all further `A`-beans I may create in the future. So I've tried to put `@DependsOn('b')` to the abstract `A`-class only, but it didn't work: probably this annotation is not inherited.

So is there any other elegant way to achieve this behaviour instead of putting this annotation to each of subclasses?

Comment: Autowire bean B in the abstract class A. All implementations of class A will need this bean to be initialized before they are initialized

Comment: It might work, but then I will have unused field in `A`, because `A`-beans don't use `B`-bean directly. So it's also not so elegant :)

Comment: Then how is bean B dependent on A? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The dependency is transitive: via bean `C` in the middle :) But still there's a dependency.

Comment: Spring automatically takes care even if there is an indirect dependency. You don't really need to manage the dependencies. Adding some code with beans A, B, C might help understand the problem a bit more.

Comment: OK, I'll explain. Each bean of type `A` contains autowired bean `C`. And bean `C` contains autowired bean `B`. So `B` is injected to `A`, but indirectly. And this doesn't help: if I don't use `DependsOn`, then `A`-beans are being initialised before `B`.

Comment: If that's how it is, spring will automatically take care of the bean dependencies. You don't have to interfere.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question. You can check it by yourself if you want, but I have my code in front of me and the init-order is not preserved. Moreover, I believe it shouldn't be preserved in this case according to Spring specs.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. If bean C has a dependency over bean B, bean C cannot be injected into bean A without getting initialised by itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770225/spring-3-bean-instantiation-sequence Please post the code and the error you are getting when trying to instantiate without using DependsOn annotation.

Comment: @DmytroTitov did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: btw for the skeptics, my use case is this: A is a subclass of `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` and registers an ApplicationEventListener implementation called, say, X. So the base class A calls `register(X)`  Now X calls B when it gets an `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED` event where B is autowired into X. So, summarizing: the subclasses of A fire an event calling B where B is autowired to X which is "registered" on A... But without annotations B is not instantiated when the first subclass of A fires

Comment: One more data point: I was ready to use the inelegant hack suggested by @yaswanth, but I recall that my B is also a subclass of A, so it would be autowired to itself :(

Answer (score 1):

use `@Lazy` instead of `@DependsOn('b')` if solve your use case.

`@Lazy` will be initialized by container only when that bean will be accessed somewhere in code

```
@Bean
@Lazy(value = true)
public A a(){
    return new A();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't actually suit my needs: all of dependent beans have `PostConstruct` init-method which have to be called during application startup. So I can't make them be lazy (I mean I can, but it's not by design of the app).

Comment: Is it required that bean will initialized on application start up.What is the problem in initializing just before using.Is it init method time complexity is high so you are doing at start up

Comment: You are right: these inits are too time-consuming to be executed on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a custom annotation, and replace `@Service` annotation on A beans with it

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Service
@DependsOn('b')
public @interface ServiceDependingOnB { 
    String value() default "";
}
```